# assertEquals vs. assertEqual in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a difference between `assertEquals` and `assertEqual` in the python `unittest.TestCase`?

And if there is not, why are there two functions? Only for convenience?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Actually, in Python 2.6, both `assertEqual` and `assertEquals` are convenience aliases to `failUnlessEqual`. The source declares them thus:

```
# Synonyms for assertion methods
assertEqual = assertEquals = failUnlessEqual
```

In [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#deprecated-aliases), to your point, `failUnlessEqual` is explicitly deprecated. `assertEquals` carries this comment :-)

```
# Synonyms for assertion methods
# The plurals are undocumented.  Keep them that way to discourage use.
# Do not add more.  Do not remove.
# Going through a deprecation cycle on these would annoy many people.
```

So, the upshot appears to be that you should use whatever you like for Python 2.x, but tend toward `assertEqual` for Python 3.

Comment: Actually the comment about plurals is ambiguous. It says "the plurals" are undocumented. Your final sentence indicates you understand this to mean method names ending with 's', like `assertEquals`. Yet grammatically, *equals* is a singular (3rd person) form of a verb, not a plural. I think you understood correctly what the comment-writer meant, but the word 'plural' is mistaken.

Answer (score 67):

A 3.3 update: From [26.3.7.1.1. Deprecated aliases](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.html#deprecated-aliases) :

> For historical reasons, some of the TestCase methods had one or more aliases that are now deprecated. The following table lists the correct names along with their deprecated aliases:

```
Method Name   | Deprecated alias | Deprecated alias
--------------+------------------+-----------------
assertEqual() | failUnlessEqual  | assertEquals
...
```

Answer (score 35):

Not just for Python 3.x, since Python 2.7 `assertEquals` has been deprecated as well:

```
Method Name            | Deprecated alias(es)
_________________________________________________________
assertEqual()          | failUnlessEqual, assertEquals
```

From [25.3.7.1.1. Deprecated aliases](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#deprecated-aliases)

Answer (score 5):

I think this was tension between the "only one obvious way to do it" vs. "alias to make the overall code flow semantically".  Personally I found I like to read

```
failIf(some_condition)
```

over

```
assertFalse(some_condition)
```

but liked

```
assertEqual(a, b)
```

over the other two (`assertEquals(a, b)` bothers my sense of grammar).

The "only one obvious way to do it" has taken precedence going forward.

Answer (score 4):

I don't find any mention of assertEquals in http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html.  However, when I import TestCase and then do a "help(TestCase)", it's listed.  I think it's just a synonym for convenience.

Comment: Yeah, but it badly breaks the "only one obvious way to do it" mantra:-(.

Comment: @Alex - You'll get no argument from me on that.

Answer (score 2):

I know it doesn't answer the specific question, but if you got here while searching for:

```
using deprecated method assertEquals()
```

You just need to change the call to .assertEqual() (remove the 's' in equalS)