# What is the canonical way to isolate unit tests in Python with assertion-style tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, bdd

I recently asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985903/is-there-a-preferred-bdd-style-testing-framework-for-python) and realized that I'd also like to know if there's a way to achieve 'expectation' isolation with assertion-style tests. I've copy and pasted a simple example of what I mean by 'expectation' isolation.

I'm relatively new to Python, coming from Ruby/JavaScript and having testing libraries like Rspec and Jasmine has provided me with the ability to isolate 'expectations' when testing a single function. Since there doesnt seem to be an 'expectation'-style library for Python that is actively maintained, I was wondering if there's a way to achieve an equivalent testing style with either unittest or pytest (the 2 most popular Python testing libraries from what I understand).

**foo.py**

```
class Foo():
    def bar(self, x):
        return x + 1
```

**Expectation-Style/Describe-It**

**test_foo.py**

```
describe Foo:
    describe self.bar:
        before_each:
            f = Foo()

        it 'returns 1 more than its arguments value':
            expect f.bar(3) == 4

        it 'raises an error if no argument is passed in':
            expect f.bar() raiseError
```

**Unittest/assertion-style**

**test_foo.py**

```
 class Foo():
     def test_bar(x):
         x = 3
         self.assertEqual(4)
         x = None
         self.assertRaises(Error)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you are asking about module that provides `describe/it/expect` assertion style in python?

Comment: I did ask that in another question. This question is aimed at achieving the same functionality with unittest/pytest's assertion-style testing. chepner provided an answer that I believe is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unittest` module is part of the standard library.

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.f = Foo()

    def test_bar(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.f.bar(3), 4)

    def test_missing_argument(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.f.bar())
```

Comment: So each 'it' expectation would be a test function instead, that makes sense. From what I understand, adding a docstring to the test would provide a similar 'it does this' description to the test output as well, correct? One other thing I've been having trouble finding is how I would check for a function being called. Not a mock, but an actual function. If I have a function that conditionally calls 1 of 3 functions, how would I check which function got called without testing the end result, which should be a test of that function vs the calling the function.

Comment: You can also pass a string as an additional parameter to the `assert*` methods, which is displayed if the assertion fails. As for identifying which of three functions is called by another, I think you would need to use a mock, as well as reengineer the function to allow for [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). But you'll probably get a better answer from someone who knows more than me if you post a new question.

Comment: Note that `assertEqual` is preferred against `assertEquals` since the latter is [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930995/assertequals-vs-assertequal-in-python) in python-3.x.

Comment: That's a typo on my part, but I'll just add comment rather than fixing to emphasize that there are two very similarly named methods, and I used the wrong one :)